# Automatically tag with git and gradle during Android assemble

Tags: android, git, gradle, versioning

I saw that a lot of people is using git tag to read the version during build and then assemble however i would like to do the opposite.

I already have my version name and code dynamically created in my build.gradle and i want to tag the current git commit every time i do an assemble (which changes the version name) with the version name PLUS the current variant name (so i need it to be variant independent). What i am not able to do is read the current version name from the variant i am building, so, something like:

```
task gitTag(type: Exec) {
    exec {
        currentVersionName = android.variant.name
        commandLine 'git tag -a ' + currentVersionName
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assemble') {
        task.dependsOn = gitTag
    }
}
```

On top of this, since it appears no one is doing this, is this a bad approach?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Do you need latest tag to know (programatically) the latest version? If yes, you can use modified `GIT-VERSION-GEN` approach with `git describe --match "v[0-9]*" --abbrev=0 HEAD` (assumung that you use `vX.Y.Z` tags to name released versions).

Comment: No, i need to execute "git tag" every time i run "assembleRelease" or "assembleBeta" with the correct tag name after variant evaluation